# string.ToLower() and string.ToLowerInvariant()

Tags: c#, .net, string

What's the difference and when to use what? What's the risk if I always use `ToLower()` and what's the risk if I always use `ToLowerInvariant()`?

Comment: Maybe you should instead normalize strings to uppercase. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386042.aspx

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550213/in-c-sharp-what-is-the-difference-between-toupper-and-toupperinvariant

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Depending on the current culture, ToLower might produce a culture specific lowercase letter, that you aren't expecting.  Such as producing `ınfo` without the dot on the i instead of `info` and thus mucking up string comparisons.  For that reason, ToLowerInvariant should be used on any non-language-specific data.  When you might have user input that might be in their native language/character-set, would generally be the only time you use ToLower.

See this question for an example of this issue:
[C#- ToLower() is sometimes removing dot from the letter "I"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6600954/84206)

Answer (score 79):

**TL;DR:**

When working with "content" (e.g. articles, posts, comments, names, places, etc.) use `ToLower()`.  When working with "literals" (e.g. command line arguments, custom grammars, strings that should be enums, etc.) use `ToLowerInvariant()`.

**Examples:**

=*Using `ToLowerInvariant` incorrectly*=

In Turkish, `DIŞ` means "outside" and `diş` means "tooth".  The proper lower casing of `DIŞ` is `dış`.  So, if you use `ToLowerInvariant` incorrectly you may have typos in Turkey.

=*Using `ToLower` incorrectly*=

Now pretend you are writing an SQL parser.  Somewhere you will have code that looks like:

```
if(operator.ToLower() == "like")
{
  // Handle an SQL LIKE operator
}
```

The SQL grammar does not change when you change cultures.  A Frenchman does not write `SÉLECTIONNEZ x DE books` instead of `SELECT X FROM books`.  However, in order for the above code to work, a Turkish person would need to write `SELECT x FROM books WHERE Author LİKE '%Adams%'` (note the dot above the capital i, almost impossible to see).  This would be quite frustrating for your Turkish user.

Comment: I am a professional developer for many years and I knew this as "The Turkish 'I' Problem" before. However, this was by far the best and also shortest explanation I read so far. Thank you!

Comment: Very good explanation even for a Turk like me :) More information for the curious can be found at [Does Your Code Pass The Turkey Test?](https://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html).

Answer (score 48):

I think this can be useful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolowerinvariant.aspx

**update**

> If your application depends on the case of a string changing in a predictable way that is unaffected by the current culture, use the ToLowerInvariant method. The ToLowerInvariant method is equivalent to ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture). The method is recommended when a collection of strings must appear in a predictable order in a user interface control.

also

> ...ToLower is very similar in most places to ToLowerInvariant. The documents indicate that these methods will only change behavior with Turkish cultures. Also, on Windows systems, the file system is case-insensitive, which further limits its use...

http://www.dotnetperls.com/tolowerinvariant-toupperinvariant

hth

Comment: @danyolgiax Please can you elaborate further? cant infer its usablity from msdn's link. Thanks

Comment: yes ToLowerInvariant is not working in Turkish as expected. İ becomes ı

Answer (score 30):

`String.ToLower()` uses the default culture while `String.ToLowerInvariant()` uses the invariant culture. So you are essentially asking [the differences between invariant culture and ordinal string comparision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492799/difference-between-invariantculture-and-ordinal-string-comparision).

Comment: No he isn't. "Ordinal" is a *third* option - a slightly different way to "ignore" current culture. The distinction isn't relevant in discussing `ToLower` variants; Ordinal vs. invariant just changes the "sort order" of two strings, doesn't change equality comparison.