# C#- ToLower() is sometimes removing dot from the letter "I"

Tags: c#, string, culture

We have noticed a weird error when calling ToLower() on certain strings.

The input string is:

```
string s = "DocumentInfo";
string t = s.ToLower();
// sometimes, t == documentinfo
// other times, t == documentınfo  (note dot is missing from i - INCORRECT)
```

We are passing the string to a web service query downstream, so it is causing problems for us.

My initial guess is that it has something to do with Culture or UICulture, as some of our pages customize these settings per user.

Could this be the issue? Is there are way I can force this to work properly?

UPDATE 2011.07.06

I found that I could duplicate the issue by setting Culture to **tr-TR**.
Not sure if other cultures are impacted.

Comment: what is your current culture?

Comment: Turkey, by any chance? Note: all "system" strings (i.e. strings that have meaning to code rather than to humans) should almost always be compared, sorted, capitalised, etc using the *invariant* culture (as already answered), or *at the minimum* some known fixed culture.

Comment: Here's the obligatory [Turkey Test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html) link.

Comment: Re your edit, indeed Turkey is the notorious one for this - hence the "Turkey test" (search for it), very common in IT

Comment: yep, I tested with tr-TR and that isolated the problem. thanks

Comment: Related: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/TransAtlantic-Time-Trap.aspx

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try using [`String.ToLowerInvariant()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolowerinvariant.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
s.ToLower(new CultureInfo("en-US", false));
```

If you get a different result, your CultureInfo.CurrentCulture may be set to something else.

Comment: While this will probably work fine, the invariant culture is more convenient (you don't need to look it up by key), and more indicative of our intent, IMO

Comment: The user should just know that the Invariant in ToLowerInvariant assumes they want lower case general English. Per MSDN: It is associated with the English language but not with a country or region.

Comment: But using the invariant culture is not the same thing as using the en-US culture. If you see ToLowerInvariant, you can assume it's going to be a non-visible string used for internal computation. If you see "en-US", you have no idea what's going on. Also, the first is so much easier to write.

Comment: CultureInfo seems undefined?