# How to compare character ignoring case in primitive types

Tags: java, string, character, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I am writing these lines of code:

```
String name1 = fname.getText().toString();
String name2 = sname.getText().toString();
aru = 0;

count1 = name1.length();
count2 = name2.length();
for (i = 0; i < count1; i++)
{  
    for (j = 0; j < count2; j++)
    { 
        if (name1.charAt(i)==name2.charAt(j))
            aru++;
    }
    if(aru!=0)
        aru++;
}
```

I want to compare the `Character`s of two `String`s ignoring the case. Simply using `IgnoreCase` doesn't work. Adding '65' `ASCII` value doesn't work either. How do I do this?

Comment: you can use `Character.toLowerCase` or `Character.toUpperCase`to make all to lower case or upper case and compare it.

Comment: @idiottiger That works in the English language, but not in every language.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class of Java API has various functions you can use.

You can convert your char to lowercase at both sides:

```
Character.toLowerCase(name1.charAt(i)) == Character.toLowerCase(name2.charAt(j))
```

There are also a methods you can use to verify if the letter is uppercase or lowercase:

```
Character.isUpperCase('P')
Character.isLowerCase('P')
```

Comment: This doesn't work in every language, for example, this will fail for the Turkish language

Comment: @PeterBruins - could you please share a sample of Turkish text which will make the code fail ?

Comment: In the turkish language, 'İ' (Uppercase I with a dot) is the uppercase version of 'i'. For more information: https://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/

Answer (score 16):

You can't *actually* do the job quite right with `toLowerCase`, either on a string or in a character.  The problem is that there are variant glyphs in either upper or lower case, and depending on whether you uppercase or lowercase your glyphs may or may not be preserved.  It's not even clear what you *mean* when you say that two variants of a lower-case glyph are compared ignoring case: are they or are they not the same?  (Note that there are also mixed-case glyphs: `\u01c5, \u01c8, \u01cb, \u01f2` or ǅ, ǈ, ǋ, ǲ, but any method suggested here will work on those as long as they should count as the same as their fully upper or full lower case variants.)

There is an additional problem with using `Char`: there are some 80 code points not representable with a single `Char` that are upper/lower case variants (40 of each), at least as detected by Java's code point upper/lower casing.  You therefore need to get the code points and change the case on these.

But code points don't help with the variant glyphs.

Anyway, here's a complete list of the glyphs that are problematic due to variants, showing how they fare against 6 variant methods:

1. Character `toLowerCase`
2. Character `toUpperCase`
3. String `toLowerCase`
4. String `toUpperCase`
5. String `equalsIgnoreCase`
6. Character `toLowerCase(toUpperCase)` (or vice versa)

For these methods, `S` means that the variants are treated the same as each other, `D` means the variants are treated as different from each other.

```
Behavior     Unicode                             Glyphs
===========  ==================================  =========
1 2 3 4 5 6  Upper  Lower  Var Up Var Lo Vr Lo2  U L u l l2
- - - - - -  ------ ------ ------ ------ ------  - - - - -
D D D D S S  \u0049 \u0069 \u0130 \u0131         I i İ ı   
S D S D S S  \u004b \u006b \u212a                K k K     
D S D S S S  \u0053 \u0073        \u017f         S s   ſ   
D S D S S S  \u039c \u03bc        \u00b5         Μ μ   µ   
S D S D S S  \u00c5 \u00e5 \u212b                Å å Å     
D S D S S S  \u0399 \u03b9        \u0345 \u1fbe  Ι ι   ͅ ι 
D S D S S S  \u0392 \u03b2        \u03d0         Β β   ϐ   
D S D S S S  \u0395 \u03b5        \u03f5         Ε ε   ϵ   
D D D D S S  \u0398 \u03b8 \u03f4 \u03d1         Θ θ ϴ ϑ   
D S D S S S  \u039a \u03ba        \u03f0         Κ κ   ϰ   
D S D S S S  \u03a0 \u03c0        \u03d6         Π π   ϖ   
D S D S S S  \u03a1 \u03c1        \u03f1         Ρ ρ   ϱ   
D S D S S S  \u03a3 \u03c3        \u03c2         Σ σ   ς   
D S D S S S  \u03a6 \u03c6        \u03d5         Φ φ   ϕ   
S D S D S S  \u03a9 \u03c9 \u2126                Ω ω Ω     
D S D S S S  \u1e60 \u1e61        \u1e9b         Ṡ ṡ   ẛ
```

Complicating this still further is that there is no way to get the Turkish I's right (i.e. the dotted versions are different than the undotted versions) unless you know you're in Turkish; none of these methods give correct behavior and cannot unless you know the locale (i.e. non-Turkish: `i` and `I` are the same ignoring case; Turkish, not).

Overall, using `toUpperCase` gives you the closest approximation, since you have only five uppercase variants (or four, not counting Turkish).

You can also try to specifically intercept those five troublesome cases and call `toUpperCase(toLowerCase(c))` on them alone.  If you choose your guards carefully (just `toUpperCase` if `c < 0x130 || c > 0x212B`, then work through the other alternatives) you can get only a ~20% speed penalty for characters in the low range (as compared to ~4x if you convert single characters to strings and `equalsIgnoreCase` them) and only about a 2x penalty if you have a lot in the danger zone.  You still have the locale problem with dotted `I`, but otherwise you're in decent shape.  Of course if you can use `equalsIgnoreCase` on a larger string, you're better off doing that.

Here is sample Scala code that does the job:

```
def elevateCase(c: Char): Char = {
  if (c < 0x130 || c > 0x212B) Character.toUpperCase(c)
  else if (c == 0x130 || c == 0x3F4 || c == 0x2126 || c >= 0x212A)
    Character.toUpperCase(Character.toLowerCase(c))
  else Character.toUpperCase(c)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can change the case of String before using it, like this

```
String name1 = fname.getText().toString().toLowerCase(); 
String name2 = sname.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
```

Then continue with rest operation.

Comment: Beware of the [Turkish locale problem](http://mattryall.net/blog/2009/02/the-infamous-turkish-locale-bug).

Comment: Won't string replacement be slow if we are processing a "huge" sequence of "large" strings ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to consider the Turkish I problem when comparing characters/ lowercasing / uppercasing:

I suggest to convert to String and use toLowerCase with invariant culture (in most cases at least).

public final static Locale InvariantLocale = new Locale(Empty, Empty, Empty);
str.toLowerCase(InvariantLocale)

See similar C# 
[string.ToLower() and string.ToLowerInvariant()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225808/string-tolower-and-string-tolowerinvariant)

Note: Don't use String.equalsIgnoreCase
http://nikolajlindberg.blogspot.co.il/2008/03/beware-of-java-comparing-turkish.html

Answer (score 3):

This is how the JDK does it (adapted from OpenJDK 8, [String.java/regionMatches](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.regionMatches%28boolean%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cint%2Cint%29)):

```
static boolean charactersEqualIgnoringCase(char c1, char c2) {
  if (c1 == c2) return true;

  // If characters don't match but case may be ignored,
  // try converting both characters to uppercase.
  char u1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1);
  char u2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2);
  if (u1 == u2) return true;

  // Unfortunately, conversion to uppercase does not work properly
  // for the Georgian alphabet, which has strange rules about case
  // conversion.  So we need to make one last check before
  // exiting.
  return Character.toLowerCase(u1) == Character.toLowerCase(u2);
}
```

I suppose that works for Turkish too.

Comment: The `char` type is outmoded, and should be avoided, as it is unable to represent even half of the characters defined in Unicode.

Comment: Is that actually a problem? Java can represent code points as combinations of 2 chars. What else should be used anyway?

Comment: See the `codePoint` methods such as [`String::codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()) and [`Strimg::codePointAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt(int)). These methods work with `int` rather than `char`.

Comment: And read [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Answer (score 1):

Generic methods to compare a char at a position between 2 strings with ignore case.

```
public static boolean isEqualIngoreCase(char one, char two){
    return Character.toLowerCase(one)==Character .toLowerCase(two);
}

public static boolean isEqualStringCharIgnoreCase(String one, String two, int position){
    char oneChar = one.charAt(position);
    char twoChar = two.charAt(position);
    return isEqualIngoreCase(oneChar, twoChar);
}
```

Function call

```
boolean isFirstCharEqual = isEqualStringCharIgnoreCase("abc", "ABC", 0)
```