# combining charAt and IgnoreCase?

Tags: java

(Beginner with java here),

I'm making a simple game where the user can type if he wants to play again or not. However, I want the game to keep replaying as long as he types yes, Yes or any combination of yes. So As long as the first letter is `y` the game continues. Ex)

Game Runs

```
} while(newGame.charAt (0) == 'y');
```

But I also want java to ignore if it is `Y` or `y`, I tried combining `charAt(0) == 'y'` and IgnoreCase but couldn't figure it out.

I know I could just do `&& 'Y'`, but seems like it is unnecessary code?

Thanks

Comment: Just do something like `Character.toLowerCase(charAt(0)) == 'y'`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare character ignoring case in primitive types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223176/how-to-compare-character-ignoring-case-in-primitive-types)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A neat trick for case insensitivity is to simply convert to lowercase before you compare. The class `Character` contains a number of useful functions for manipulating characters, so you can do this:

```
} while (Character.toLowerCase(newGame.charAt(0)) == 'y');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method `String.startsWith`. Its name is explaining what it is doing. To ignore case sensitivity, you can use `String.toLowerCase` (or `toUpperCase` respectivly).

This will result in the following:

```
if (newGame.toLowerCase().startsWith("y")) {
    // Play again
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logic you described here I think you should use `||` instead of `&&`.

And for ignoring case sensitivity you can Use [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)'s class static method `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()`. Example  -

```
while(Character.toUpperCase(newGame.charAt (0)) == 'Y'){
 ...
 ...
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could ignore the case sensitivity by simply converting the character to lower case or upper case using `toLowercase()` or `toUppercase()` methods.

```
while(Character.toLowerCase(newGame.charAt(0)) == 'y');

while(Character.toUpperCase(newGame.charAt(0)) == 'y');
```