# Using || OR Operator within If Statements alongside characters

Tags: java

I'm very new to programming in general, and I'm having a bit of trouble with a program I'm writing in Java to help calculate my final grade in a class. This part of the program asks me what letter grade I would like to receive, and then determines if that input is valid. For example, if I typed into the keyboard that I wanted to receive a letter grade of "Z", because that is not a valid grade, I would like my program to output "Invalid Input" and exit. The code I have written below is not producing any syntax errors, but it outputs "Invalid Input" for every letter grade I choose, even A, B, and C (inputs that should be valid). Any help in understanding what's wrong is more than welcome.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

char desiredGrade

System.out.print("What letter grade do you want to achieve for the course? ");
desiredGrade = input.next().charAt(0);
if (desiredGrade != 'A' || desiredGrade != 'B' || desiredGrade != 'C'){
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

In addition to this, it would be helpful to not have to worry about case sensitivity with the inputs. I know I can use .ignoreCase() or .equalsIgnoreCase() with strings, but I'm not quite sure how to implement that with char.

Comment: This `(desiredGrade != 'A' || desiredGrade != 'B' || desiredGrade != 'C')` is always true, because `desiredGrade` cannot be equal to all those characters simultaneously. If you want to check it is not equal to any of them, you need `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: Beyond that: please understand that this isnt programming school where people work with you *through* the different aspects of your homework.

Comment: Okay, but is the OR operator not supposed to divide those? As in "this OR this OR this", so they aren't simultaneous? Is there a way I could do this correctly?

Comment: upper/lower: Character.toUpperCase(desiredGrade) == 'A'

Comment: Note that `if("ABC".indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(desiredGrade))==-1)` should also work .

Comment: @ConnorHale It's _and_ because you want to check if it is _not A and not B and not C_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say `desiredGrade = 'A'`

```
if (desiredGrade != 'A' || desiredGrade != 'B' || desiredGrade != 'C'){
```

The first condition will be false, but the second and third will be true. So

```
if (false || true || true)
```

Will result always in `true`.

The way to do it is using operator AND &&

```
if (desiredGrade != 'A' && desiredGrade != 'B' && desiredGrade != 'C'){
```

This way, if the user decides to input 'A' the operation will be

```
if (false && true && true){
```

Resulting in `false`. And if the user inputs 'Z', the operation will be

```
if (true && true && true){
```

That will result `true` and execute the `Invalid input` output.

**EDIT**
As it has been mentioned. The user may input 'a' (lowercase) for which condition `desiredGrade = 'A'` will be `false` since `'a' != 'A'` (is not equal).

So it will be wise to convert desiredGrade to uppercase before the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

[see this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10223361/3737393)

For Upper- and Lowercase you can wrap your char in Character and then call `toLowerCase` and check the input and the expected value on Lowercase.

In your example

```
desiredGrade != 'A' || desiredGrade != 'B' || desiredGrade != 'C'
```

If you want to use the `||` operator you have to do it like that

```
if(!(desiredGrade == 'A' || desiredGrade == 'B' || desiredGrade == 'C')){
}
```

That way you check if the Input is A, B, or C and if not then `exit`

Answer (score 1):

Try out

```
(desiredGrade != 'A' && desiredGrade != 'B' && desiredGrade != 'C')
```

Basically, you want to check if desiredGrade is different than A *and* different than B *and* different than C, print out invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (! Arrays.asList ('A', 'B', 'C').contains (Character.toUpperCase (desiredGrade))) {
    // your error handling
}
```