# Compare user input (char) with other char

Tags: java, char, compare

How could I compare the input that I receiving from the user to a char?
I will receive a letter from the user (That could be uppercase or lowercase) and then compare it whit the desired letter.

Example:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
char inlet;

System.out.println("Enter letter:");
inlet = input.next().atChar(0);

if(inlet == "A"){
System.out.println("Same letter");
}
```

How can I use `toLoweCase()` in my if statement?

Comment: You can use 'java.lang.Character.toLowerCase()' method to convert a char to lower case. Otherwise you could just compare it with both upper and lower case letters. Also, I think you should use 'A' instead of "A" as atChar method returns a char instead of a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare character ignoring case in primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223176/how-to-compare-character-ignoring-case-in-primitive-types)

Comment: I am trying to do this: `if(Character.toLowerCase(inlet.charAt(0) == 'A')){
      System.out.println("Valid letter");
    }` but this error appears: **Cannot invoke charAt(int) on the primitive type int
**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `toUpperCase(char ch)` or `toLowerCase(char ch)`[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) to convert the user input and compare like below:

```
if ( Character.toLowerCase(inlet) == 'a' ){

}
```

OR

```
if ( Character.toUpperCase(inlet) == 'A' ){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

char primitives are backed by the ASCII value holder integer numbers. So, if the question is

> how to compare two char values?

then the answer would be to have a look on ASCII representations of char values, and to the fact, that every char can be represented as integer by casting it to int:

```
char c1 = 'a';
char c2 = 'c';
System.out.println((int)c1);
```

for example, 'a' is represented by corresponding integer ASCII value 97, 'A' - by 65, 'b' - by 98 and so on (pay attention on the capitalization).

So, you can easily write `if (c1>c2){..//code here..}` and corresponding ASCII integer numbers are to be compared respectively.

However, if the question is

> how to change the case of a given char?

then the answer provided by @royalghost would work fine.