# How could I get my program to check if a word is a palindrome irrespective of the case entered by the user

Tags: java, palindrome

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pailindrome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a word");
        String ori = sc1.nextLine();
        isPailindrome(ori);
        if (isPailindrome(ori))
            System.out.println(ori + "is a Pailindrome");
        else
            System.out.println(ori + "is NOT a Pailindrome");
    }
    public static boolean isPailindrome(String ori) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = ori.length() - 1;
        while (i < j) {
            if (ori.charAt(i) != ori.charAt(j)) {
                return false;
            }
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The code works perfectly I'm just confused how I will get it to work irrespective of the case
inputted by the user. For example aBba is a palindrome but It says it's not in the code I've done. I
would like any help if possible thanks.

Comment: Just convert the string to either uppercase or lowercase, and then compare. `ori = ori.toUpperCase()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare character ignoring case in primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223176/how-to-compare-character-ignoring-case-in-primitive-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert all of the letters to lowerCase before you start the processing.

You can write your own function or use `toLowerCase()` String function.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pailindrome {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter a word");
  String ori = sc1.nextLine();
  ori = ori.toLowerCase();
  isPailindrome(ori);
  if (isPailindrome(ori))
 }
 System.out.println(ori + "is a Pailindrome");
} else {
 System.out.println(ori + "is NOT a Pailindrome");
}
}
public static boolean isPailindrome(String ori) {
 int i = 0;
 int j = ori.length() - 1;
 while (i < j) {
  if (ori.charAt(i) != ori.charAt(j)) {
   return false;
  }
  i++;
  j--;
 }
 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take the input and call toUpper(); that way when you check to see if it is a palindrome, all of the characters are uppercase.

```
String ori = scr.nextLint();
if(isPalindrome(ori.toUpperCase()))
//do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert all the cases to lowercase/uppercase before checking the palindrome

`isPailindrome(ori.toLowerCase());`

Answer (score 1):

Zoom in from both ends and adjust the case as required.

```
    public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
        int len = str.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len >>1; i++) {
            if (Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i)) != 
                    Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(len - i - 1))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```