# Using equalsIgnoreCase returns "char cannot be deferenced"

Tags: java

I am counting the number of times e or E occurs from String phrase in the numTimesE method. I came across the error when running the  code below. I fixed below by using || in my if statement. I was wondering why this error came up, and if there was a possible way to still use String.equalsIgnoreCase(), or something easier than || in an if statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Testing
{
    //numTimesE method
    public static int numTimesE(String phrase)
    {
        int countE = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++)
        {
            if (phrase.charAt(i).equalsIgnoreCase('e'))
                countE++;
        }//end of for
        return countE;

    }// end of numTimesE

    //main method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int num = numTimesE("Earl why are you yelling?");
        System.out.println(num);

    }//end of main
}//end of Testing
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare character ignoring case in primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223176/how-to-compare-character-ignoring-case-in-primitive-types)

Comment: Problem appears that you ware using primitive type `char` variable as it was reference. Notice that only reference type variables (classes, interfaces, enums, arrays,..., in other words subtypes of Object) can have methods. Primitive types don't (which is one of main reason why we call them primitive). So `'a'.someMethod(..)` is invalid and that is what error message describes.