# Is there a more effective way to write a function that checks if a word is abecedarian? JAVA

Tags: java

Here is a code that I wrote for my assignment:

> Write a method called `isAbecedarian` that takes a `String` and returns a `boolean` indicating whether the word is abecedarian (characters arranged alphabetically), ignoring case.

I am trying to figure out if there is a better way to write this function than what I wrote here:

```
public static boolean isAbecdarian(String s) { 
    int index = 0;
    char c = 'a'; 
    while (index < s.length()) {
        if (c > s.charAt(index)) {
            return false;
        }
        c = s.charAt(index); 
        index = index + 1;
            
    }
    return true;    
}
```

Comment: You haven't ignore case, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223176/how-to-compare-character-ignoring-case-in-primitive-types

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better way:

```
public static boolean isAbecdarian(String s) { 
    String upper = s.toUpperCase();
    for (int i = 1; i < upper.length; i++) {
        if (upper.charAt(i - 1) > upper.charAt(i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Admittedly, the differences are relatively small.  But (IMO) the code is easier to understand with a `for` loop and no temporary variables.

And you forgot the "ignore case" requirement.

Finally, I have intentionally not added an explicit `null` check to avoid NPEs.  That would (IMO) be incorrect.  The spec you have been given doesn't require this, and this is not a reasonable requirement to infer in this context.  It is better to let an *unexpected* (and incorrect per the spec) `null` argument produce an NPE for the programmer to notice and fix.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the task is to determine whether the letters of a particular word are arranged alphabetically, for example the word *act* since the letter *c* comes after the letter *a* in the English alphabet and similarly the letter *t* comes after the letter *c*.

Notes after the code.

```java
public class Abecedarian {
    private static boolean isAbecedarian(String word) {
        boolean isAbecedarian = false;
        if (word != null) {
            int length = word.length();
            if (length == 1) {
                isAbecedarian = true;
            }
            else if (length > 1) {
                word = word.toLowerCase();
                char c = word.charAt(0);
                for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
                    if (c <= word.charAt(i)) {
                        isAbecedarian = true;
                        c = word.charAt(i);
                    }
                    else {
                        isAbecedarian = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return isAbecedarian;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isAbecedarian("I"));
        System.out.println(isAbecedarian("art"));
        System.out.println(isAbecedarian("cat"));
    }
}
```

- A single letter word must be abecedarian.
- For words with more than one letter, each successive letter must have a unicode code point that is greater than, or equal to, its predecessor letter. For letters in the English alphabet the unicode code point is the same as the [ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

The above code prints the following output:

```
true
true
false
```

Comment: Well yea ... but you can write it in 9 lines rather than 23.

Comment: Yea ... that's another thing.  It is a bad idea to "defend" against NPEs.  If a method is called with a `null` argument when the spec for the method doesn't say that `null` is meaningful, then trowing an NPE is the **desired** behavior.  It is better than trying to make good by treating `null` as a special case and returning a (dubious) value.

Comment: It is better to let the NPE happen, so that the programmer who called the method with an invalid argument gets a stacktrace to debug.

Comment: Now ... maybe ... if you are building software in a domain where a software crash *must not ever happen* (e.g. because innocent people will be killed), then maybe a defensive `null` check might be a sensible thing to do.  But such applications are a minuscule minority.  And that is certainly not applicable to the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about a 1 liner:

```
public static boolean isAbecdarian(String s) {
    return s.toLowerCase().chars().reduce(0, (a, b) -> a >= 0 && b >= a ? b : -1) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP will have fun explaining that to their teacher :-)

Comment: I like your words, magic man.