# lambda query to lower in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I'm having an issue toLower() in lambda query.  I have this code

```
var filterResult = articleList
                        .Where(m => m.Summary
                            .Contains(filteredModel.Keyword) || m.Body.Contains(filteredModel.Keyword) || m.Headline.Contains(filteredModel.Keyword) 
                            || m.Title.Contains(filteredModel.Keyword))
                        .AsQueryable();
```

I need to add toLower() method as sql. For example:

```
var filterResult = articleList
    .Where(m => m.Summary.toLower()
        .Contains(filteredModel.Keyword.toLower()) || m.Body.toLower().Contains(filteredModel.Keyword.toLower()) || m.Headline.toLower().Contains(filteredModel.Keyword.toLower()) 
        || m.Title.toLower().Contains(filteredModel.Keyword.toLower()))
    .AsQueryable();
```

As above code, lambda doesn't allow to use.  I wonder if there is other way to do to achieve this.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: .toLower() should be .ToLower()

Comment: In C# the method is `ToLower()` not `toLower()`, not sure if that is a typo or not, but `ToLower()` should be perfectly legal to use.

Comment: @MarkByers He'll get a not supported exception because there is no ToLower method in SQL.  What he needs is a case insensitive contains in SQL.

Comment: Its probably that EF / Linq2SQL etc can't map the function into the database. If you have a case insensitive collation on your table, you shouldn't need ToLower?

Comment: @nonnb you're right. I used EF ORM before. I got an error this method doesn't allow to use. But I'm working on OpenAccess ORM which allow it to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ToLower` should work, try breaking it up into different lines to narrow down which check is failing - remember it won't execute until you actually pull the results down e.g.

```
var keyword = filteredModel.Keyword.ToLower();
var filterResult = articleList.Where(m => m.Summary.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(keyword));
filterResult = filterResult.Where(m => m.Body.ToLower().Contains(keyword));
filterResult = filterResult.Where(m => m.Headline.ToLower().Contains(keyword));
filterResult = filterResult.Where(m => m.Title.ToLower().Contains(keyword));
```

Also just an FYI - if your converting to lower case for culture-independant comparison then you should be using [ToLowerInvariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolowerinvariant.aspx)...or better yet using [ToUpperInvariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupperinvariant.aspx) as it's more [reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225808/string-tolower-and-string-tolowerinvariant).

Comment: The problem still remains that those methods aren't supported by the LINQ provider.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same with

```
    .Where(m => m.Summary.IndexOf(filteredModel.Keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 
       || m.Body.IndexOf(filteredModel.Keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 
       || m.Headline.IndexOf(filteredModel.Keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 
       || m.Title.IndexOf(filteredModel.Keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
```

which I believe should be supported by your Linq provider

You could make this neater [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/444818/630920) by creating an extension method

```
public static bool Contains(this string source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp) {
  return source.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
}
```

So you could then do

```
.Where(m => m.Summary.Contains(filteredModel.Keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
           || m.Body.Contains(filteredModel.Keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
           || m.Headline.Contains(filteredModel.Keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
           || m.Title.Contains(filteredModel.Keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```