# Bad coding practise when using ToLower() and not ToLowerInvariant()

Tags: c#, tolower

I was writing my code for searching in a database, so I wrote this code:

```
public IEnumerable<Company> SearchInCustomers(string Search)
{
    return Company.Where(w => 
         (w.CompanyName.ToLower().Contains(Search.ToLower())) ||
         (w.City.ToLower().Contains(Search.ToLower()))).OrderBy(w => w.Id);
}
```

I works fine and I thought it was good code. When I started to check my code with e.g. SonarCube (This is to review your code and spot bad code) it said that I was using the `.ToLower()` wrong. It showed me a message why and how to use this (if you want to see the message let me know) and it gave me a [link](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/STR02-J.+Specify+an+appropriate+locale+when+comparing+locale-dependent+data).

It said I need to use `.ToLowerInvariant()`, but I had never heard of this.

So now I am wondering, is it really bad to use `ToLower()`, and should I use `.ToLowerInvariant()` or just it as I always did?

**Edit:**

The input is always in the same language, it is used in the country I live in and there is no way it can delete something. There is no "weird" input in the `Search`.

Comment: Is not it for Java?

Comment: @anatol It is for every language that is like `c`.

Comment: It works for you doesnt mean it works for everybody else. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolowerinvariant%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Arendax this link in your post I means

Comment: In a nutshell, English upper & lowercase are always equivalent (A & a, B & b) but in other languages this is not always the case (pun intended!).

Comment: Did you actually *read* the duplicate?

Comment: does this answer help? - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19778131/3091161

Comment: @Jamiec yes. Otherwise I would not link it..

Comment: Did you read the accepted answer? It answers your question exactly.