# Case Insensitive Interpretation C#

Tags: c#, console, string-comparison

I'm making a text game, and I have one method for getting the input from the player and another for processing that input. However, it only works if the player types the command all in lowercase. I want it to ignore case.

```
        public string GetInput()
    {
        var Test = true;

        while (Test)
        {
            response = Console.ReadLine();
            if (validWords.Contains(response))
            {
                Test = false;
                ProcessInput(response);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry, I do not understand.");
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
public void ProcessInput(string response)
    {
        switch (response)
        { //Switch statements for responses here
        }
    }
```

I've tried using a few other responses I've found here, but they all still only work with lowercase input(using LINQ, string.IndexOf/Equals/etc.). Ideas?

Comment: What is the content of validWords? If these are all lower case strings then just convert the user input to a lower case word and then run the search. IE _response = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();_

Comment: They are all lowercase-- where do I put ToLower?

Comment: Just convert the input to lower case. No other changed needed then. (in particular inside the switch statement)

Answer (score 3):

Use [string comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which ignores string case as second parameter for `Contains` method:

```
validWords.Contains(response, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Why do you use `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` isn't ordinal the better choice?

Comment: @Toshi agree, ordinal comparer will be a better choice

Answer (score 2):

You can add `.ToLower()` after the readline, as followed:

`response = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();`

Everything read in from the console will be in lowercase.

You can read more about the `ToLower` method in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78f86at(v=vs.110).aspx).

Furthermore, also see the following question if you expect input of certain cultures: [string.ToLower() and string.ToLowerInvariant()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225808/string-tolower-and-string-tolowerinvariant).

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me—can't believe it was so simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can make every input you receive, Lower-Case, using ToLower().

Example:

```
string response = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the text you have to lower using .ToLower().

Answer (score -1):

You're currently using `if (validWords.Contains(response))` to check whether the user's response is contained within your validWords list. (I'm assuming).

What you can do is use the following LINQ expression:

```
if (validWords.Where(w => w.ToUpper().Equals(response.ToUpper())).Count() == 1)
```

This validates against both upper case strings.

Comment: This will work but  won't be as efficient as simply converting console input to lower case (1 operation). Your solution unnecessarily executes ToUpper() on every valid word (1 operation on console input + n operations on validWords).