# Why does "i" get replaced with "ı"

Tags: c#, xml, localization, culture

I received a crash report from an application which was trying to read XML from a file it had previously written. After requesting the user send me the file, I compared it with what should have been written and found a really odd problem I haven't come across before.

Some (but not all) of the `i` characters had been replaced with `ı` - a dotless i. For example, a node named "title" was fine, but a node named "initialdirectory" had the first i replaced, the second was left alone, i.e. `ınitialdirectory`.

Until today I wasn't even aware there was such a character, but now I do and I just don't know how it was written like that - the XML was written using an `XmlWriter` with UTF8 encoding. Just a normal everyday write, nothing complicated.

I normally (well, since getting Resharper and it yells at me for skipping the parameter) use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` when doing `IndexOf` etc, but I'm at a loss on how I'm supposed to do this when writing data, unless I'm supposed to start changing thread cultures.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue before, and if so, what's the best way to deal with it?

Comment: This is "Turkish i" issue - search for it. Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring/15464440#15464440 or better yet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550213/in-c-sharp-what-is-the-difference-between-toupper-and-toupperinvariant/3550226#3550226

Comment: perhaps you have a `typo` where you are wanting to do the replace I mean the `i` and the `l` are right by each other on the keyboard

Comment: well I am not `Turkish` so I wouldn't know that..LOL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Turkish there are two i's: one with a dot, `i`, and one without a dot, `ı`. In upper case the first one has a dot, `İ`, and the second one hasn't, `I`.

At some point your program is converting `InitialDirectory` to lower case according to the default locale, which is known to be Turkish in some parts of the world. To fix the problem you can convert cases using a fixed, known locale, such as American English.

**Update:** Even better, use the [`ToLowerInvariant()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolowerinvariant.aspx) method which converts a string to lower case in the ["invariant culture"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c5zdc6a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: I think it's better to use invariant culture instead of `en-US`. To make this easier, there's even a shortcut for that: [`ToLowerInvariant()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolowerinvariant.aspx).

Comment: @Joni - thanks for the answer. You are correct that I am indeed doing `ToLower` on the strings in this class. I do actually use `ToLowerInvariant` - but generally only on data that the user directly enters or modifies. Anything fixed I still use `ToLower` on... perhaps I should rethink that one! Sounds like you have hit the nail on the head though, I shall change them and see if the user still has the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: There's a good article about this issue here: http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html