# Custom TypeInfoResolver to manage polymorphic deserialization in System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

I am following this official [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?source=recommendations&pivots=dotnet-7-0#configure-polymorphism-with-the-contract-model) and also this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/87545).

Based on what I read I created my `PolymorphicTypInfoResolver` which is almost identical to the example.

```cs
public class NativePolymorphicTypInfoResolver : DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver {
    public override JsonTypeInfo GetTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options) {

        JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo = base.GetTypeInfo(type, options);

        Type baseValueObjectType = typeof(ValueObject);
        if (jsonTypeInfo.Type == baseValueObjectType) {
            jsonTypeInfo.PolymorphismOptions = new JsonPolymorphismOptions {
                TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "$mytype",
                IgnoreUnrecognizedTypeDiscriminators = true,
                UnknownDerivedTypeHandling = JsonUnknownDerivedTypeHandling.FailSerialization,
                DerivedTypes = {}
            };
        }

        return jsonTypeInfo;
    }
}
```

However when it comes to the `DerivedTypes` member I would like to be able to set it dynamically like this

```cs
var types = Assembly
    .GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyBaseClass)))
    .ToArray();
```

and then set the array, or the list if projecting with `ToList()` like this

```cs
DerivedTypes = types.Select(t => new JsonDerivedType(t, t.Name.ToLower())).ToArray()
```

However I get a syntax error stating that `Property or indexer 'JsonPolymorphismOptions.DerivedTypes' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only` which is clear. But I am for sure missing something that could be very stupid...

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compilation error is caused because [`JsonPolymorphismOptions.DerivedTypes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsonpolymorphismoptions.derivedtypes) is a preallocated **read-only collection property** of type `IList<JsonDerivedType>`.  As such you cannot assign it to the value returned by some LINQ query.

Instead you must add your derived types to it after construction:

```
public override JsonTypeInfo GetTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
    JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo = base.GetTypeInfo(type, options);

    Type baseValueObjectType = typeof(ValueObject);
    if (jsonTypeInfo.Type == baseValueObjectType) {
        jsonTypeInfo.PolymorphismOptions = new JsonPolymorphismOptions {
            TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "$mytype",
            IgnoreUnrecognizedTypeDiscriminators = true,
            UnknownDerivedTypeHandling = JsonUnknownDerivedTypeHandling.FailSerialization,
        };
        var types = Assembly
            .GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ValueObject))); // Fixed MyBaseClass => ValueObject
        foreach (var t in types.Select(t => new JsonDerivedType(t, t.Name.ToLowerInvariant()))) // Fixed ToLower() => ToLowerInvariant
            jsonTypeInfo.PolymorphismOptions.DerivedTypes.Add(t);
    }

    return jsonTypeInfo;
}
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XhASqr).

Do note that, as of .NET 8, I would recommend you use a [`JsonTypeInfo` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts#modifiers) rather than subclassing `DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver` since [`WithAddedModifier()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsontypeinforesolver.withaddedmodifier) works with arbitrary `IJsonTypeInfoResolver` instances including [source-generated contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonserializercontext?view=net-8.0).

To do that, first define the following extension method:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static void AddNativePolymorphicTypInfo(JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
    {
        Type baseValueObjectType = typeof(ValueObject);
        if (jsonTypeInfo.Type == baseValueObjectType) {
            jsonTypeInfo.PolymorphismOptions = new JsonPolymorphismOptions {
                TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "$mytype",
                IgnoreUnrecognizedTypeDiscriminators = true,
                UnknownDerivedTypeHandling = JsonUnknownDerivedTypeHandling.FailSerialization,
            };
            var types = Assembly
                .GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ValueObject))); // Fixed MyBaseClass => ValueObject
            foreach (var t in types.Select(t => new JsonDerivedType(t, t.Name.ToLowerInvariant()))) // Fixed ToLower() => ToLowerInvariant
                jsonTypeInfo.PolymorphismOptions.DerivedTypes.Add(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Then set up your options e.g. as follows:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver() // Or use some source-generated context if you prefer
        .WithAddedModifier(JsonExtensions.AddNativePolymorphicTypInfo),
    // Add other options as required, e.g.
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(rootObject, options);
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/odXZRV).

Nodes:

- When creating JSON contracts, always be sure to uppercase or lowercase metadata names in the [invariant locale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolowerinvariant?view=net-8.0).  This ensures that contracts will be identical across locales and avoids e.g. the [Turkish I problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15822236).
- I had to replace `Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyBaseClass)))` with `.Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ValueObject)))` to make my demo of your code work.
- `DerivedTypes = {}` compiles because it uses [read-only collection property initializer syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#object-initializers-with-collection-read-only-property-initialization).  This syntax automatically calls `Add()` when the property being initialized is a preallocated collection and the value is a series of objects appearing in braces `{` and `}`.  Unfortunately this syntax is not usable to automatically populate the collection with the results of a LINQ query, so adding in a more traditional syntax is required.

---

**Update**

In your [modified fiddle from comments](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jLsZhV) you are expecting to use the version of `AddNativePolymorphicTypInfo()` above to automatically add polymorphic type discriminators when serializing values that are declared to be subtypes of `ValueObject`.  In the code shown in your question, you prevent this with the following check:

```
if (jsonTypeInfo.Type == baseValueObjectType)
```

You would need to check

```
typeof(ValueObject).IsAssignableFrom(jsonTypeInfo.Type)
```

If you want to automatically add polymorphic discriminators to all derived types of `ValueObject` even when serialized explicitly as derived types, you must modify `AddNativePolymorphicTypInfo()` as follows:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static void AddNativePolymorphicTypInfo(JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
    {
        if (typeof(ValueObject).IsAssignableFrom(jsonTypeInfo.Type) && !jsonTypeInfo.Type.IsSealed) {
            jsonTypeInfo.PolymorphismOptions = new JsonPolymorphismOptions {
                TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "$mytype",
                IgnoreUnrecognizedTypeDiscriminators = true,
                UnknownDerivedTypeHandling = JsonUnknownDerivedTypeHandling.FailSerialization,
            };
            // This query is likely to be slow so you might want to cache all types assignable to typeof(ValueObject) in a lazy static singleton
            var types = Assembly
                .GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && jsonTypeInfo.Type.IsAssignableFrom(t));
            foreach (var t in types.Select(t => new JsonDerivedType(t, t.Name.ToLowerInvariant()))) // Fixed ToLower() => ToLowerInvariant
                jsonTypeInfo.PolymorphismOptions.DerivedTypes.Add(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Do note however that System.Text.Json does not allow polymorphic type identifiers to be emitted when serializing values that are declared as `sealed` types.  If any of your derived `ValueObject` types are sealed, you must use a different approach such as inserting the the discriminator as a synthetic property.

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BejS4H).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Always great value. Also thanks for the corrections and other suggestion like the invariant locale. I expanded a little bit the tests you provided to support more use cases. I am sorry that I don't know at all NUnit so you may find the code I little bit verbose. I have found some strange bahaviors in my tests, that you can check in this [fork](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CzYcXl). The first two tests try to serialize only the valueObject, when declaredit as base or as derived. The latter two try to serialize the object in an inner class, again as base or as derived.

Comment: @user23137927 - the rules on stack overflow are are to ask [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735) and to include all relevant code [in the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @user23137927 - That being said, when you do `JsonSerializer.Serialize(rootObject, BuildSerializerOptions())` the declared type is `MyValueObject` not `ValueObject` so the polymorphic type info is not added.  You need to force the declared type to be `ValueObject` e.g. by doing `JsonSerializer.Serialize<ValueObject>(rootObject, BuildSerializerOptions())`. And in `TEST 4` you won't get a polymorphic type identifier because, in `RootObjectTwo`, your property is declared as `MyValueObject? ValueObject` and so is not polymorphic.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/jLsZhV.

Comment: I get your point on asking one question per post. However I don't  think my comment, and the fiddle fork, were related to a different question. I've just expanded the tests to different use cases within the same context. However this is not important and does not change the terms of my question. I am trying to migrate an application which uses Newtonsoft and I often struggle with mechanisms that can be implemented in new developments but not applied to systems that have been in production for years. I think that feature parity is far to be achieved. Again, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @user23137927 - there's no penalty for asking more questions, in fact there's often a reward in the form of upvotes and bonuses for accepting answers.  Also, sometimes a multipart, omnibus question won't ever get an answer because no one person happens to know all the answers.  And it's not really clear from your comment what exactly your needs are, a second question might help the community to understand your needs more clearly.

Comment: Let's take this question as an example: To be able to migrate I should take in consideration (1) modify all the entities to change current types to their respective base class to achieve polymorphic deserialization; (2) modify all the `private` setters in `init` or pollute the models with a `JsonInclude` attribute; (3) add a private parameterless constructor or add a `JsonConstructor` attribute. Current implementation is based on `behind the scene` pieces of code that are simply configured on serializer options (contract resolver, converters, others). Too many impacts for the value we get :)

Comment: And this is only for what it concerns this question/answer. I have another question which also introduce other issues. We would like to migrate because of performance gain. However it becomes costly and risky for us. I know that the STJ has been designed with different objectives in mind to achieve better ecurity and performance by design, but it's hard to justify such in ainvestment for the value we get.

Comment: @user23137927 - I added an update based on your fiddle, but it would have been better to include all relevant info in your question as a [mcve].  With regards to your comments about migrating to System.Text.Json, I don't really have any recommendation one way or another.  Json.NET is stable and will be around for a long time, so if the business case to make the move isn't there, don't do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, again, for your help. Really appreciate the knowledge and advices you provided. And by the way, congratulations for your very deep knowledge on this. Really appreciate :)