# UserManager.FindByEmailAsync returns null, but the user exists in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

`UserManager.FindByEmailAsync` returns `null`, but the user exists in the database.

The code below explain the strange problem:

```
var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
var test = new Data.ApplicationDbContext().Users.First(x => x.NormalizedEmail == email);
var usermail = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

Console.WriteLine(test == null);      //false
Console.WriteLine(usermail == null);  //true
```

##### EDIT

Also via `_userManager` itself, the desired user is obtained:

```
var test = _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NormalizedEmail == email);
var usermail = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

Console.WriteLine(test == null);      //false
Console.WriteLine(usermail == null);  //true
```

It should be noted that the user was not created in a "conventional" manner, but by Data-Seed (in `OnModelCreating`):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    var users = new (string email, string name)[] {
        ("xyz@gmail.com", "admin")
    };

    var appUsers = users.Select(x => new ApplicationUser
    {
        Email = x.email,
        NormalizedEmail = x.email,
        NormalizedUserName = x.email,
        UserName = x.email,
        EmailConfirmed = true,
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    }).ToArray();

    var role = new IdentityRole("Admins") { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };
    var roleToUser = appUsers.Select(x => new IdentityUserRole<string> { RoleId = role.Id, UserId = x.Id });

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasData(appUsers);
    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(role);
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(roleToUser);
        
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

Comment: You did not say what are your actually wanting? You just presented some code and then said nothing!

Comment: @TanvirArjel Can you point to missing information after the title and code? I expect that `(await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email)) == new Data.ApplicationDbContext().Users.First(x => x.NormalizedEmail == email);`

Comment: `var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);` is returning the email that is being used for external login. So have you created an user with that email please?

Comment: Can you add your `ApplicationDbContext()` code please?

Comment: I checked the UserManager's [FindByEmailAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1401) which calls [FirstOrDefaultAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/UserStore.cs#L634) on the `Users` set just like you do. The only difference between your query and what the UserStore does would in line [1414](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1414) but this can be ignored since FindByEmail returns `null` for you.

Comment: Therefore: Is the `Users` set in the DbContext really associated with the `User` class registered with  the `IdentityUser`? I mean maybe the `_userManager` is operating on a completely different db set or it operates on an [InMemoryUserStore](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/test/InMemory.Test/InMemoryUserStore.cs)?

Comment: For better debugging, could you compare `dbContext.Users.Count()` with `_userManager.Users.Count()` to see if they deviate? Or execute your query on the set managed by the UserManager: `_userManager.Users.First(x => x.NormalizedEmail == email);` and check whether this yields a result. If not, then your dbset is different from what the UserManager operates on...

Comment: @B12Toaster `Count()`? Much more than that! `_userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NormalizedEmail == email)` return the desired user... i edit the question, thank!

Comment: How did you create User by `Data-Seed`, share us the code.

Comment: @TaoZhou i added the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can see in the source-code links in the comments I made to your OP
[FindByEmailAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1401) performs a [NormalizeKey](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1410) before it actually starts searching for the user.

```
email = NormalizeKey(email);
```

This `NormalizeKey(email)` is done by the [UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer.cs#L9) that will do the following string operation on your email

```
return key.Normalize().ToUpperInvariant();
```

Now the part of your code that is causing the "strange" behaviour is the missing call to normalize in your code when creating the user:

```
var appUsers = users.Select(x => new ApplicationUser
{
    Email = x.email,
    NormalizedEmail = x.email,
    NormalizedUserName = x.email,
    UserName = x.email,
    EmailConfirmed = true,
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
}).ToArray();
```

Not normalizing the email will still make it discoverable via the users table as this simply compares the `NormalizedEmail` (which you did not normalize when you created the user) with the not-normalized email you pass as argument:

```
_userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NormalizedEmail == email);
```

...however, `userManager.FindByEmailAsync` will [normalize](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1410) it first and [afterwards](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1411) do the search...

```
_userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
```

...and therefore not find the user.

Change your code to the following:

```
// inject via using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
protected ILookupNormalizer normalizer;

var appUsers = users.Select(x => new ApplicationUser
{
    Email = x.email,
    NormalizedEmail = normalizer.Normalize(x.email),
    NormalizedUserName = normalizer.Normalize(x.email),
    UserName = x.email,
    EmailConfirmed = true,
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem just by clearing the users that were registered and I registered again, soon after FindByEmailAsync() started to find the Users, I'm not sure why this happens but I'll leave my report here because it might help someone. good luck!

Comment: Interesting, I had the same problem. Not sure why it then starts to work with the exact same email.

Answer (score 0):

For `NormalizedEmail` and `NormalizedUserName`, it should be uppercase letter.

Try

```
var appUsers = users.Select(x => new ApplicationUser
{
    Email = x.email,
    NormalizedEmail = x.email.ToUpper(),
    NormalizedUserName = x.email.ToUpper(),
    UserName = x.email,
    EmailConfirmed = true,
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
}).ToArray();
```

Comment: I would not use this in production as it deviates from the way Identity normalizes values. Simply using `ToUpper` is problematic as it depends [on the current culture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper?view=netcore-2.2#System_String_ToUpper) which may [not contain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3550226/2477619) uppercase variants; Also a call to [normalize](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize) is missing. So `FindByEmailAsync` still may not necessarily work with [international domains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2071250/2477619).