# How to check if last char of an array string ends with "A"

Tags: c#

I have made an array where the user inputs several names, I then want the program to print them out. If the letter ends with "a" I want it to change color. Here's what I mean in code.

```
        Array.Sort(stodents);

        Console.WriteLine("----------");

        for (int i = 0; i < stodents.Length; i++)
        {
            if (What do I type here?)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(stodents[i]);
        }
```

So yeah I want it to make the string blue when it doesn't end with an A and magenta when it does.

Comment: have you checked EndsWith in string ? I think this can resolve your problem

Comment: I treid but I didn't get it to work.

Comment: the requirement says that last character of array. Then this will work. I think there may be some other issue in understanding question.. Can you share  your sample array and output ?

Comment: Someone shared how to do it, I am very new to this and it's confusing. But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [String.EndsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith?view=net-5.0) method.

```
if(stodents[i].EndsWith('a'))
```

The method checks if the string ends with a specified char/string (depending on the overload you use) and returns true if it finds a match.

You could also use the overload with [StringComparison enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith?view=net-5.0#System_String_EndsWith_System_String_System_StringComparison_) if you want to make it case-insensitive check

For example,

```
if(stodents[i].EndsWith("a",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: For strings entered by the user, `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` would probably be more appropriate than `OrdinalIgnoreCase` as it respects the casing rules of the current culture. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550213/in-c-sharp-what-is-the-difference-between-toupper-and-toupperinvariant

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example:

```
   Array.Sort(students);
    Console.WriteLine("----------");

    foreach (string student in students)
    {
        if (student.EndsWith('A')
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(student);
    }
```

NOTE:

1. In C#, common to use "foreach()" instead of a "for()" loop.
2. One solution is to use the .Net API [StringEndsWith()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith?view=net-5.0)
3. One problem is that your code most end with 'A'. You can "generalize" your code to accomodate either upper or lower case by using [String.ToLower()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower?view=net-5.0).

PS: As Anu6is correctly pointed out (and as the documentation I cited shows), you can also use an optional `StringComparison comparisonType` argument for a case-insensitive comparison.  The drawback is then you must use a string (`"A"`) instead of a character (`'A'`).

Comment: In regards to your point 3, EndsWith also accepts a StringComparison in which you can use StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase

Comment: For strings entered by the user, `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` would probably be more appropriate than `OrdinalIgnoreCase` as it respects the casing rules of the current culture. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550213/in-c-sharp-what-is-the-difference-between-toupper-and-toupperinvariant