# How do I search a string of text for words that begin with specific letters and then print them?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, loops

I have a string of text and I need to check the string for words that begin with the letter A, then print said words to console.

So far, I have converted the string into its individual parts but am not sure how to go about using substring or `StartsWith` and an if statement to then feed it to `Console.WriteLine`.

This is my code so far.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string text = "Anna and Jenny went to America to eat some apples";
  string[] words = text.Split(' ');
  
  foreach (string word in words)
  {
  
  }
```

Comment: `if (word.StartsWith('A')) Console.WriteLine(word);`. Or the case-insensitive equivalent: `if (word.StartsWith("A", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) Console.WriteLine(word);`.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two options here, we can write:

```
if (word.StartsWith("A")) { Console.WriteLine(word); }
```

Running this, would give you "Anna", "America".

or

```
if (word[0] == 'A') { Console.WriteLine(word); }
```

Running this, would give you "Anna", "America".

These two options are case sensitive, if this is your objective then great, if you're wanting a solution which accepts both cases, we can do:

```
if (word.StartsWith("A", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) { Console.WriteLine(word); }
```

or

```
if (word[0].ToString().Equals("A", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) { Console.WriteLine(word); }
```

Running the above would get you: "Anna", "and", "America" and "apples".

What the latter example does (`word[0]`) is it gets the first character from your word to compare, my examples provide you with three ways you can compare the first letter of the string, note that using `word[0]` will always return a single character (data type char) so you won't be able to test for more than one character at a time!

Comment: Your last snippet does not work as you are comparing a char with a string

Comment: You're right, updated!

Comment: You could also write `word[0] == 'A' || word[0] == 'a'`

Comment: @gunr2171 Not quite, the second example is demonstrating case insensitivity - you'll see that's done in the first example already.

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, you could, many ways to write it, just keeping it simple really given OP is a beginner :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! While I was mucking around offline I figured out that I could get the console to print "Anna" "and" "America" "Apples" by putting in two if statements to include both the upper and lower case A.

    foreach (string word in words) 
    { 
    if (word.StartsWith("A")) 
    { 
    Console.WriteLine(word); } 

    if (word.StartsWith("a")) 
    {
    Console.WriteLine(word); } }

Comment: But now that I look at your code and compare it to mine, I think what I've done is too 'easy' and will probably cause errors of some kind. I'm just too green to see any. Also sorry for my poor formatting. I couldn't figure out a way to format code into a comment!

Comment: @Kageus No problem, your solution that you came up is good but ideally you'd put that into one if statement like so `if (word.StartsWith("A") || word.StartsWith("a"))`. The double pipe `||` means "or", so either of these conditions must be true for your `Console.WriteLine` to print in the console. You won't get bugs as such since you're checking for specific casing but if you were to introduce case insensitivity, you'd need to remove the other if statement as you'd get double results. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can try *matching* word with a help of *regular expressions*; if we define word as

> Non-empty sequence of *letters* and *apostrophes*

you can put it as follow

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string text = "Anna and Jenny went to America to eat some apples";

var words = Regex
  .Matches(text, @"A[\p{L}']*")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value);

foreach (string word in words) {
  //TODO: Relevant Code Here  
}
```

Pattern `A[\p{L}']*` explained:

```
A         - letter A followed by
[\p{L}']* - Zero or more letters (\p{L}) or apostrophes
```

If you want to *ignore case* (`apples` will be included), just do it:

```
var words = Regex
  .Matches(text, @"A[\p{L}']*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
  ...
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ajyUA2)

Note, that matching is *more accurate* in case when *punctuation* is used e.g.

```
string text = "Anna, would you like to go to America, Africa or Antarctica?";
```

where we expect to get `{Anna, America, Africa, Antarctica}`, if you `Split` you'll get `{Africa}` only.

Answer (score -1):

you just have to use the StartsWith and ToUpper Or ToLower for case sensitive :

```
foreach (string word in words)
  {
      if (word.ToUpper().StartsWith("A")) {
        Console.WriteLine(word);
      }
  }
```

Comment: If you're going to transform the entire casing of `word` (which, IMO, is wasteful), at least use [`ToUpperInvariant()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550213/in-c-sharp-what-is-the-difference-between-toupper-and-toupperinvariant)

Answer (score -1):

Same thing as Adrian's excellent answer, but in [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) form:

```
String text = "Anna and Jenny went to America to eat some apples";
var words = text.Split(" ".ToCharArray()).Where(x => x.StartsWith("a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
foreach (var word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Comment: Why `.Split(" ".ToCharArray())` instead of simple `.Split(' ')`?

Comment: Because that's the way I always write it; so if I need to add other things besides a space to split on, they can be listed in there and the code doesn't need other changes.